# Add image to google chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have the following area chart using the Google charts API.  I'd like to be able to dynamically add markers along the bottom like follows (in orange).

[image]

HTML would be best, but can settle for just images if that's not possible.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to get coordinates of all hAxes and then add svg image on each coordinate.

[jsfidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2hg63yj/7/)

```
//Get all svg group component as an collection
var g_collection = document.getElementsByTagName('g');

//Convert the collection into array
var g_array = Array.prototype.slice.call( g_collection, 0 );

//Filter the array to get hAxis group
var hAxis = g_array.filter(function(g){
    return g.logicalname && g.logicalname.indexOf("hAxis") > -1 && g.logicalname.indexOf("title") === -1
});

//Draw marker on each hAxis
hAxis.forEach(function(g, index){
    //Create marker using svg image
    var marker= document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");

    //Get coordinate
    var x = g.childNodes[0].getAttribute('x');
    var y = g.childNodes[0].getAttribute('y');

    //Set attributes on the marker
    marker.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x - 20);
    marker.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y - 70);
    marker.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "image url");
    marker.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "50px"); 
    marker.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "50px"); 
    marker.setAttributeNS(null, "style","cursor:pointer");

    //Add mouse click event listener on the marker
    marker.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
        alert("mouse down on marker"+index);
        //add your event code
    });

    //Add the marker in the hAxis group
    g.appendChild(marker);
});
```